# Error while using preg_replace()

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to run the following code.

```
// Do the replace
$row->text = preg_replace("#{".$this->plg_tag."}".$tagcontent."{/".$this->plg_tag."}#s", $plg_html, $row->text);

// end foreach
```

But, i get this warning.

> Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '{' in /home/girmag/public_html/plugins/content/jw_sigpro/jw_sigpro.php on line 510

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark due to lack of information, but my guess is that either `$this->plg_tag` or (more likely) `$tagcontent` contains a `#` which is causing the problem because... well, that's your delimiter!

Try this:

```
preg_replace("(\{(".preg_quote($this->plg_tag).")\}"
        .preg_quote($tagcontent)."\{/\1\})s", $plg_html, $row->text);
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a syntax error in line 525: } // END CLASS

Comment: How would I know how to fix that, though? It probably means you didn't copy my code correctly or something...

Comment: Sorry.  I'm totally stabbing in the dark here.  NO idea what I'm doing.  Just a joomla newbie running into problems.  I just copied an pasted your code, though . .